# slide up bottomsheet by dragging button up(android)

Tags: android

I want to control my bottom sheet's state with one button.

The control button is located at the top of the bottom sheet layout.

And if i drag up the control button, bottom sheet will expand.

I tried to search what event triggers bottomsheet's expansion, but couldn't find out.

So my question is, what method in bottomsheetbehavior.class triggers stage change?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diiLv.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way to change state based on button click

```
 controlBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if (bottomSheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED){

           bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);

                }
     else {
     bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    } 
});
```

The callback that gets triggered when your bottomsheet state changes is

```
 bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomsht, int newstate) {
               if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
                behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            }

            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View view, float v) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
But the clicking control button should not make bottom sheet expanded.

I want user to drag this button. And as the button goes up, bottom sheet should follow

Comment: then you have to include that button inside bottomsheet layout

Comment: yes i did, but if i drag the entire bottom sheet, it is expanded as well.
I want to avoid it, but don't know how to

Comment: check my edited answer you can check if user is gragging then keep collapsed

Comment: Clicking button is not what I want. What I want is  only dragging the button is able to expand / collapse the bottom sheet